# Force ignore one dependency's dependency from being installed by npm/yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, pouchdb, yarnpkg

My nodejs project uses some libraries. One library [`pouchdb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb) will try to install quite a lot of dependencies. There is one called [`leveldown`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/leveldown), which will try to download Node.js header from Internet and then rebuild everything from scratch. Actually I don't need the `leveldown` at all. But their community suggest me to privately fork a `pouchdb` and the modify the package.json to exclude any dependency I don't need.

Here is my general question to npm/yarn folks. Is it possible to prevent particular library from being downloaded, while running `npm install` or `yarn install`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible to exclude a sub-dependency from the installation.

---

However, in your case, you don't need to privately fork `pouchdb`. PouchDB has custom builds published as npm packages: https://pouchdb.com/custom.html.

If you want to install pouchdb for use in-browser, `npm install pouchdb-browser`.

If you're using other storage adapters (like the in-memory adapter), you may want to `npm install pouchdb-core` instead. Note that `pouchdb-core` doesn't include some functions that ship with `pouchdb`.

- If you need to use `query()` or `viewCleanup()`, you need to install `pouchdb-mapreduce` and pass it as a plugin.
- If you need to use `replicate()` and `sync()`, you need to install `pouchdb-replication` and pass it as a plugin.

Example usage:

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb-core')
  .plugin(require(WHATEVER_STORAGE_ADAPTER_YOU_ARE_USING))
  .plugin(require('pouchdb-mapreduce'))
  .plugin(require('pouchdb-replication'));
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a reasonable solution. The annoying thing is actually not exactly `leveldown` but `node-gyp`, it tries to download header files or current nodejs and then rebuild everything from scratch. But behind a corporate proxy, there will be some difficulties to download stuff from internet, especially when I easily upgrade nodejs (which means need to download corresponding header again)

Answer (score -1):

sure, it's totally possible, for yarn just add:

```json
    "resolutions": {
        "leveldown": "npm:empty-npm-package",
        "other-package-to-exclude": "npm:empty-npm-package"
    }
```

there are plenty of poorly managed libraries in npm, yarn don't react to this yet, so solution above is a bit of a trick. Vote for stackoverflow question and [github issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4611) to bring yarn's and npm's attention to the problem and make a nice solution, e.g. `"exclude-libraries": ["lib1", "lib2"]`

(for those who prefer to stay with `npm`, you can use `overrides` instead of `resolutions`)

Comment: WARNING: This will replace it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/empty-npm-package, a package published by a random, unknown npm user. If at any time this user is compromised, you could be installing malware on your computer. It is far better to use something like `"file:empty"` where `empty` is a directory in your project with an empty `package.json` in it.

Comment: Furthermore, `resolutions` only works with yarn; npm has a different field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/7127751