# npm equivalent of yarn resolutions?

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg

Is there an `npm` equivalent of the [yarn resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) functionality? There is no mention of it in the npm package.json [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json).

For example, I want to install `lerna@3.3.2` and one of its dependencies (@lerna/publish) at 3.3.2 as well. Currently doing that with `yarn` like so, but would prefer to use npm and not manually change `package-lock.json` or anything dodgy like that.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "lerna": "3.3.2",
},
"resolutions": {
  "@lerna/publish": "3.3.2"
}
```

Comment: Do you know about `npm shrinkwrap` ? This might work for you.
See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override nested NPM dependency versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Since NPM 8.3 the equivalent to yarn resolutions is called *overrides*.

To make sure the package foo is always installed as version 1.0.0 no matter what version your dependencies rely on:

```
{
   "overrides": {
     "foo": "1.0.0"
   }
 }
```

Documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

Why and how the feature was added it's discussed in the [RFC](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/main/accepted/0036-overrides.md) and discussion on the topic was indexed on this github [issue](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/129)

Comment: This answer helped me to solve

https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/issues/228

An npm package whose github repo was archived referenced an old npm package causing errors when upgrading to a newer version of NodeJS.

https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/commit/9a1b386020049ecf5d5c8ec70817afd7b6241fed
https://github.com/andrewrk/node-s3-client/blame/master/package.json#L40

the offending packaged was updating in the repo however a new version was not pushed to npm, so the npm package was essentially broken forever.

Answer (score 66):

This does not seem to be supported by npm natively, however this package aims to add this functionality:

https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions

Comment: @Gajus: [This commit message](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions/commit/68cc61f3f1594fc2875b6092a409d25ebada3b52) suggests it should now work on npm 7. The corresponding version of `npm-force-resolutions` is `0.0.10`.

Comment: 2022, it **is supported**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/1115187

Answer (score 60):

[npm](/questions/tagged/npm) is due to support [`overrides`](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/pull/129), which is equivalent to yarn's `resolutions`.

For more information about the current RFC status:

https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/accepted/0036-overrides.md

Comment: This seem to work on NPM 8.3

Comment: 2022, it **is supported** out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/1115187

Answer (score 21):

As far as I can tell, `npm-force-resolutions` does not work with [npm](/questions/tagged/npm) v7. The [`package-lock.json` format changed in v7](https://github.blog/2020-10-13-presenting-v7-0-0-of-the-npm-cli/) and `npm-force-resolutions` no longer updates the relevant fields.

However, it is relatively easy to write a script to restrict your dependency tree to only 1 version of a package, e.g.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

/* eslint-disable unicorn/prevent-abbreviations */
/* eslint-disable import/unambiguous */
/* eslint-disable import/no-commonjs */
/* eslint-disable node/shebang */

const fs = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

const main = async (resolutions) => {
  const packageLockFilePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../package-lock.json');

  for (const [name, version] of Object.entries(resolutions)) {
    const packageLock = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile(packageLockFilePath));

    const packagePaths = Object.keys(packageLock.packages);

    const deletePaths = [];

    for (const packagePath of packagePaths) {
      if (packagePath.endsWith('/' + name)) {
        if (packageLock.packages[packagePath].version !== version) {
          deletePaths.push(packagePath);
        }
      }
    }

    for (const packagePath of deletePaths) {
      for (const deletePath of deletePaths) {
        if (packagePath === deletePath || packagePath.startsWith(deletePath + '/')) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line fp/no-delete
          delete packageLock.packages[packagePath];
        }
      }
    }

    await fs.writeFile(
      packageLockFilePath,
      JSON.stringify(packageLock, null, '  '),
    );
  }
};

main(require('../package.json').resolutions);
```

This script simply removes all links to dependencies that do not satisfy `resolutions` defined in `package.json`.

To execute the script, just add it to `package.json` `scripts` and define `resolutions` field, e.g.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node bin/fix-package-lock.js"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "webpack": "5.6.0"
  }
}
```

`resolutions` is simply a map of package names and the exact versions of those packages that should be kept in the dependency tree, i.e. the above configuration will remove all versions of [webpack](/questions/tagged/webpack) that are not `5.6.0`. As long you install `webpack@5.6.0` version as a dependency of the project you are working with, this will guarantee that all packages load the same version of webpack.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone reading this, [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) is now a supported feature of npm since version `8.3.0` :party: