# React js app - high severity vulnerability - immer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, immer.js

- After installed react-router-dom.
- I saw that I had a vulnerability.
- exactly that:

[image]

I didn't find much useful information for solve.
Has anyone ever encountered this problem?

Comment: Don't worry about this particular issue since it's only for a development dependency. You can try `npm audit fix`; it might fix it.

Comment: @AKX I tried..: "1 vulnerability required manual review and could not be updated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temp workaround until the third party packages update their dependencies to the newest [immerjs](https://github.com/immerjs/immer#readme) version (>=8.0.1) you can use [yarn resolutions](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) to use the specified fixed immer version `>=8.0.1`:

updates in the `package.json`

```
"devDependencies": {
  "immer": "8.0.1",
},
"resolutions": {
  "immer": "8.0.1"
}
```

NOTE: Don't forget to run `yarn install` after these changes.

A [npm equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416312/npm-equivalent-of-yarn-resolutions) is maybe [npm-force-resolutions](https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions).

Answer (score 0):

-Find immer into package-lock.json
-Update version to 8.0.1
-Remove node_modules
-run script `npm i`
-Enjoy