# (node:40872) [DEP0135] DeprecationWarning: ReadStream.prototype.open() is deprecated

Tags: typescript, file-upload, graphql, nestjs

GraphQLUpload of apollo server express works in version of 12.X.X But in node 14.X.X its throw the error:

Token erroror: invalid signature
(node:40872) [DEP0135] DeprecationWarning: ReadStream.prototype.open() is deprecated
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:40872) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Answer (score 4):

This problem arises after the versions of GraphQLUpload, the simplest solution is to put the following in the package.json.

```
"resolutions": {
    "fs-capacitor": "3.0.0"
}
```

after this run `npm install` after this it should work for you.

Comment: thanks, but what does it mean? what does it do?
any docs you can share?

Comment: @fafa.mnzm, `resolutions` works for `yarn`. If you use NPM then in the `package.json` add  `overrides` (more details:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/1115187 )