# found 1 high severity vulnerability (react-native-svg)

Tags: react-native, node-modules, react-native-svg

I'm trying to create a SVG component.
I have this problem after run command "npm i".
I think versions between packages aren't compatible.
How to fix this or create SVG component without react-native-svg package?
Thank a lot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmLWH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to `package.json`:

```
{ 
  // scripts, dependencies, etc.

  "resolutions": {
    "css-what": "5.0.1"
  },
}
```

Remove `lock` file. Install the packages. Check if the app is still working. If works then keep the configuration (and ignore the warnings) else revert it.

Since you are using `npm`, you may wanna first refer this thread: [npm equivalent of yarn resolutions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52416312/11613622)

Comment: It doesn't work with my case, are there other ways to create svg without this package ?

Comment: I am not well experienced with `react-native`, but the vulnerability of [`css-what`](https://github.com/fb55/css-what) is safe to ignore unless you yourself (or some package) use it to parse CSS selectors such that they would cause DoS. You can read the advisory here: https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-q8pj-2vqx-8ggc