# Why are there extra required dependencies in package-lock.json?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, package.json

React recently released a new version that has breaking changes to the TypeScript typings ([Can be read about here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24304)). Packages that require "@types/react": "*" target this new version automatically and cause my project to break.

I thought that I'd go to the projects that have this style of requirement and either ask them to change the dependency to optional or remove it. Then I thought I'd be more proactive and make a pull request to make the change myself and get some experience contributing to open source.

However, I have yet to find where this change would be made in the project. I have looked through the first 5 packages that have this problem and have yet to find where @types/react is required.

As an example, in my package-lock.json file the listing for @types/react-redux shows that it requires @types/react: "*"

[image: @types/react-redux entry in package-lock.json file]

So I go to the [npm page for @types/react-redux](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react-redux) and follow the link to the [github page](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-redux) (I also verified that I'm on the most recent version). I would expect the required packages to be found in the package.json file there, and they all are *except* @types/react.

[image: contents of package.json for @types/react-redux]

We are having a heck of a time trying to get our project working again after the changes to React being automatically pulled in because of these required "*" versions of @types/react.

Can anyone help educate me as to where this is coming from so that I could either make pull requests for these projects or ask the maintainers to make the change?

Comment: In `yarn` (v1), you can use the [`resolutions` field](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) in `package.json` to force a specific version. Recent versions of `npm` offer [similar functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/14357) with the [`overrides` field](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) in `package.json`. Might these be the shovels you can use to dig your way out?

Comment: @spender I think that might be what we have to do. It's unfortunate that there's not a non "hard-coded" solution to this, but I think it'll have to do for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because [`index.d.ts` imports `react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/6231835a34bd380ffce90de9af0b1f52c2259832/types/react-redux/index.d.ts#L24-L32), but since `package.json` does not contain an explicit dependency on `@types/react`, DefinitelyTyped adds it automatically to the generated [`package.json`](https://unpkg.com/@types/react-redux@7.1.24/package.json) of the npm bundle using information provided by the TypeScript compiler.

To pin the dependency version, simply add it explicitly to `package.json`, e.g.:

```json
{
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0",
        "@types/react": "16",
        "hoist-non-react-statics": "^3.3.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

(`"@types/react": "16"` is just an example - use a version or version range that fits). For a real example, see this [merged pull request](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/33979) that introduces a similar change.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for that info. So if I wanted to make PR for one of the projects in DefinitelyTyped, I'd have to add a version in the dependencies in that projects package.json file? Feels like I'd be steamrolling other users' projects if I put in "@types/react": "^17" if someone else is using 15, 16, 18, whatever (assuming that the request was approved, which I assume it wouldn't be). Is there a safer/more universal way to tell the project not to try to install the most recent version if there is a defined installation elsewhere (like my projects package.json file)?

Comment: @CaseSilva A version range, e.g. `"@types/react": ">=15 <18"` will install the latest version that satisfies the range constraints, unless your `package.json` explicitly indicates a more specific version that is still inside the range.