# I can't delete webpack 9.8.1

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm fixing an old project I had and I've realised that the webpack is giving problems. Well, when I try to remove the running version, which I don't know where it comes from, it keeps on appearing

I have tried `npm unistall -g webpack` and `npm uninstall webpack@9.8.1`
I also deleted the node modules folder, and the package.lock.json file.
I have cleared the npm cache `npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 1):

> which I don't know where it comes from

Your packages in your `package.json` can have their own dependencies (called transitive dependencies).

If you install, for example, [axios](https://npmjs.com/axios) - it will have its own [dependencies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios?activeTab=dependencies).

You can track why any package in your `node_modules` folder exists.

For this (assuming you use `npm`), you can use [npm explain](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-explain).

> webpack@9.8.1

I'm not sure where you have gotten the 9.8.1 version, because the latest version is [webpack@5.89.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack?activeTab=versions)

> I also deleted the node modules folder, and the package.lock.json file. I have cleared the npm cache npm cache clean --force

Deleting the `node_modules` and reinstalling packages will not work (see above regarding transitive dependencies).

`package-lock.json` file stores the "locks" for the versions, so you always get the same versions when you, for example, remove the `node_modules` folder and install packages again or you're installing everything on a new environment.

`npm cache` is, obviously, for caching - so you don't need to download the same version again when you run `npm install`.

---

If you need a specific `webpack` version, add it to your `package.json`, for example:

`npm install webpack@5.89.0`

If you do want to remove it completely - find the package, which has it as its own dependency, and remove the package (not sure you would want to do this).

If you want to have a specific version but don't want to have it in your dependencies, you can use the `overrides` section of the `package.json` file (please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/12993263).