My webpack is building old lodash version
I'm having some troubles with my webpack when building source for deployment. Built files are always created with lodash@4.17.10. How can I exclude the lodash from the build process or upgrade it to the desired version with npm run build
My package.json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Vue.js project",
  "author": "admin",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run dev",
    "unit": "jest --config test/unit/jest.conf.js --coverage",
    "test": "npm run unit",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "element-ui": "^2.13.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.6.11",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jszip": "^2.6.1",
    "jszip-utils": "^0.1.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "sass": "^1.63.6",
    "sass-loader": "^7.3.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-quill-editor": "^3.0.6",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^21.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-jsx": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^3.5.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.3.2",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.22.0",
    "chalk": "^2.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.6.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "jest": "^22.0.4",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^0.3.0",
    "node-notifier": "^5.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "ora": "^1.2.0",
    "portfinder": "^1.0.13",
    "postcss-import": "^11.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.8",
    "postcss-url": "^7.2.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.0",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.6",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "vue-jest": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^13.3.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.2",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 18.0.0",
    "npm": ">= 3.0.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}


In my package.json file, there is no lodash defined how can I have lodash in my webpack build.

Did you try npm install lodash@[version]? Maybe add --save to npm installl command.

Run npm why lodash – it's likely a transitive dependency.

Hi Vee, I did try both ways run the npm run build for each way but in the built file the old version is still being used.

Hi @AKX, I ran npm why lodash it does show lodash from other dependencies. Does that mean I have to upgrade every single one of them to have newer version of lodash ?

No, you can use npm's overrides. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67397982/51685

I put the npm's override in the package.json and also tried to reinstall the node_modules by deleting it and npm install again but the bulit vendor files are still at old lodash version 4.17.10.

For overrides your npm needs to be upgraded as well. it is supported in 8+.
You can try with npm force resoultion. https://github.com/rogeriochaves/npm-force-resolutions
